# error on access "The expression may not result in the name of the macro, the name of a user defined function, or [Event Procedure]"

Tags: vba, ms-access

my access project on my pc work correctly but on other pc on button got this error:
[image]

what is reason?

Comment: Looks like the other computer is missing something installed that yours is not missing. The reference seems to be on a Click event, so check the things that have code on the click event.

Comment: i have two form , this error is only one of forms , when i insert a new button without event on the form no error but create click event on button got this error.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not enough information to give you a decent answer. You need to figure out which click event, or which object, or which expression, which macro... something more - maybe start by clicking the "show help" button and see where that leads you.

Comment: oh i don't know !!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with "Trust Center Settings"  normally, you can go to trust center and enable macros to run.  File>Options>Trust Center    check Enable all macros.     Also,  sometimes a pending windows or office update will cause issues.